# Media Queries not working on smartphone

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, smartphone

I have four different sets of CSS styles for the following screen sizes:

```
(1) @media only screen and (max-width: 566px) { 
(2) @media only screen and (min-width: 567px) and (max-width: 767px) {
(3) @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 999px) {
(4) @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
```

When I resize the browser window on my desktop PC, everything works as expected. However, on smartphones (tested on Motorola Moto X 2, Samsung Galaxy Mini S4, iPhone 4s), always Media Query (3) is triggered (in both portrait and landscape view) instead of (1), despite the following [parameters](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html) of my Motorola Moto X 2:

[image]

Only when I change (1) to

```
(1) @media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
```

(1) is triggered. But this would then also cover (2) and (3), so e.g. on the iPad, (1) would trigger instead of (3). Any ideas please?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

In the internal browser of Android App "barcoo" the media queries work as expected, but not e.g. in mobile Chrome or mobile Firefox...

Comment: Try removing only and use @media screen and (max-width:320px) /*for small screen like mobile*/
{
 
} for small screen like phone

Comment: @CodeRomeos Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't work, either. And 320px would be too little for my 360px Smartphone (see table).

Comment: this might help you. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks, this was the decisive hint! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to CodeRomeos' [hint](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices), I could fix the issue like so:

Instead of

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 566px) {...}
```

I used:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 566px) {...}
```

Hope this helps you, too!